# Error when adding "--detailed-errors" parameter to Test Runner settings in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, nose

Let's say I have a file named `program1test.py`

```
import math
def test_1case1():
    assert math.sqrt(4) == 4
```

I run using the Nose Test Runner in PyDev with no parameters in Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> PyUnit

The result is as expected:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: program1test.test_1case1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "D:\Users\Samuel Louie\Documents\workspace\testpy\program1test.py", line 5, in test_1case1
    assert math.sqrt(4) == 4
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

However, I want to inspect what math.sqrt(4) actually gives. So I added `--detailed-errors` as a parameter for the Nose Test Runer.

If I run the test now, the result would be:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: program1test.test_1case1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 134, in run
    self.runTest(result)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 152, in runTest
    test(result)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\case.py", line 622, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\case.py", line 582, in run
    self._feedErrorsToResult(result, outcome.errors)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\case.py", line 513, in _feedErrorsToResult
    result.addFailure(test, exc_info)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\proxy.py", line 146, in addFailure
    plugins.addFailure(self.test, err)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715\pysrc\pydev_runfiles_nose.py", line 126, in addFailure
    err,
  File "C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715\pysrc\pydev_runfiles_nose.py", line 70, in reportCond
    error_contents = self.getIoFromError(error)
  File "C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715\pysrc\pydev_runfiles_nose.py", line 101, in getIoFromError
    import traceback;traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb, file=s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 169, in print_exception
    for line in _format_exception_iter(etype, value, tb, limit, chain):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 146, in _format_exception_iter
    for value, tb in values:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
    context = exc.__context__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__context__'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.030s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `nose.tools.eq_`:

```
from nose.tools import eq_
.....
eq_(math.sqrt(4), 4)
```

Comment: When you are using just assert, the evaluation of condition is done in the context outside of error reporting: as result assert by itself is incapable by design to report what is happening, regardless the options you use to run nose or pydv. Unittest library has other test methods, so you may look Into those - there are many speciality asserts.